# File association is variable on a file basis

Tags: aptana

I have a problem with Aptana file/editor associations. I have installed PDT into Aptana. In a directory I have three (and more) PHP files. When I open the first Aptana opens the "PHP Editor", when I open the second I get an Error ("Unsupported content type editor") and with the third Aptana opens the "PHP Source Editor". All have the same extension (`.php`). I want Aptana to open all PHP files with "PHP Editor". When I explicitly open the files that throw the error with "PHP Editor" I get the same error.

I have activated the PHP perspecive. Content Types > Text > PHP Content Type has `*.php (locked)`, Content Types > Text > PHP Source has `*.php (locked)`, too. In the file associations I have both editors (and two text editors) listed for *.php and "PHP Editor" is the default editor.

The project is a (local) GIT repository. In another project (also a GIT repository) it seams to work (all *.php files are opened in the "PHP Editor").

Can somebody explain me that "magic" and give me a tip how to solve my problem. I don't want to switch to another IDE or something like that…

**EDIT**

Here is how the different files behave:

```
                              Open With…    Open With…           Open With…
file     double click         PHP Editor    PHP Source Editor    Default Editor
-------- -------------------- ------------- -------------------- --------------
a.php    Error                Error         PHP Source Editor    Error
b.php    PHP Editor           PHP Editor    PHP Source Editor    PHP Editor
c.php    PHP Source Editor    PHP Editor    PHP Source Editor    PHP Editor
```

Like described by Sarah Kemp in her answer the different behavior of b.php and c.php is correct. But why can I not open file a.php with the PHP Editor?

**EDIT 2**

When I look at the file properties, `b.php` and `c.php` have the type "File (PHP Content Type)" and `a.php` has "File (PHP Source)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set file associations on a per file basis too, it looks like maybe that is your problem since your other repo is working correctly?

Right click on your file in the Project Explorer (this is where I tested) and choose 'Open With...' and select the editor you prefer from the sub menu. Once you have selected an editor in this list, Aptana will remember your preference for that file and use it when you double click in future - even if all other file of that type open with something else.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for that information. Is it possible to remove this memory? I think that would at least solve one part of my problem. The other is, like I tried to describe above: Opening some files explicitly ("Open With…") with the editor "PHP Editor" will throw an error. But Aptana opens other files in the same project with the "PHP Editor" without error when I choose "Open With…" > "PHP Editor". Maybe there are some bad records in that file based association storage?

Comment: Also when I choose "Open With…" > "Default Editor" I get this error with those files and the other files were opened in "PHP Editor". But the files, that are opened with the "PHP Source Editor" by double click are opened with the "PHP Editor" when I choose "Default Editor".

Comment: There is a [bug](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/3368-aptana-studio-breakes-eclipse-content-types) reported for the two content types you mentioned. 
All of the PHP files I checked are type "File (PHP Source)" and I use the PHP Source Editor without issues. What is the advantage of the PHP Editor over the PHP Source Editor? I don't have the PHP Editor as an option. Can you go to 'Window > Preferences > General > Content Types' and share the file associations listed for both PHP Source and PHP Content Type on your system?

Comment: I don't remember why I installed PDT. I think I had problems with the PHPDoc generation? I have been working with Eclipse/PDT before over a long time and there has been any feature that I couldn't get run in the native Aptana PHP support. -- You find my file associations in my question above. Or do you mean something different? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ah, I so hate it when people comment or answer without reading the question and then I do it anyway, I'm sorry. It looks like this is a [bug tagged as "Won't fix"](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4668?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel) by the Aptana team. I thought there might be some hope in changed the (locked) content type in the [plugin XML](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3648736/Eclipse-Tip-Define-Custom-Content-Types-to-Identify-Your-Data-Files.htm), but I could not find it in my installation, perhaps you can in yours.

Comment: I decided to remove PDT from Aptana. Now I am really missing PHPDoc auto generation and the search dialog from PDT. But I think, thats okay.

Comment: You could always switch to Eclipse proper with PDT - it wouldn't be a huge change from Aptana, though you would have to customize again.

Comment: Yes, of course. For any reason jumping to class and method declarations stopped working in Eclipse/PDT. So I decided to try Aptana and now I want to work with it for a while to test it. My Eclipse config is still there of course.